# Keybinding to quickly update (aka prettify) React indentation

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, visual-block

This is an example of the original code

```
<Text fontWeight="bold" size="lg" color="turquoise.500">Use Search V2 Beta</Text>
```

and I want a keyboard shortcut (say I get into visual mode and select the entire tag) and then hit something that converts it to this

```
<Text 
  fontWeight="bold"
  size="lg" 
  color="turquoise.500">
    Use Search V2 Beta
</Text>
```

another example

```
import { Box, Flex, Text, useDisclosure, Icon } from "@chakra-ui/react"
```

to

```
import { 
  Box, 
  Flex, 
  Text, 
  useDisclosure, 
  Icon } from "@chakra-ui/react"
```

### Disclaimer

I know there are tools like prettier etc, but what I want with Vim is more control over the process. I want to be very selective over what exactly I'm prettifying. I've had some git merge nightmares b/c of other team members using prettier

Comment: find a tool that can format it the way you like and use it with `:h 'formatprg'`. Once set you can `gq` visual block with it.

Answer (score 2):

Find a command line tool that can format part or whole buffer the way it suits your needs.

Integrate it with vim using `:h 'formatprg'` which then could be used with `gq`.

e.g.

Let's imagine there is a tool `jsx-beautifier` that can format standard input when `-` is provided:

```
$ cat some.jsx | jsx-beautifier -
```

Then you can add following to `.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`

```
setlocal formatprg=jsx-beautifier\ -
```

And now when in any javascript file you can do

- `gqap` reformat current paragraph using `formatprg`
- `gqiB` reformat current `{}` block using `formatprg`
- select visual lines and press `gq` to reformat it using `formatprg`
- ...